# Laravel: Add 'selected' attribute to HTML select option, either from an older value or the db

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm using laravel 7 for my web-app in which I have the same route both for creating and editing a project.
When I edit a project, I need to be able to load my view with the project's database values.
But when I change some fields and try to submit the form, in case I get a validation error, the expected behavior is to reload the view with the 'old' values, and if there aren't old values (which means that I have not changed anything in the corresponding fields), then with those that come from the db.
The problem is that I don't seem to be able to find a good way to maintain the 'old selected' attribute
after failing validation.

```
<select id="client" name="client" type="select">
<option {{(isset($project) && $project->client == 'o1') || old('client') == 'o1' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="o1">o1</option>
<option {{(isset($project) && $project->client == 'o2') || old('client') == 'o2' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="o2">o2</option>
<option {{(isset($project) && $project->client == 'o3') || old('client') == 'o3' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="o3">o3</option>
```

So for example if I have o3 in my db when I load the project to edit it, change it to o1, fail validation on another field, when the view reloads, instead of o1, o3 will be selected. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
@php
$client = (isset($project)) ? $project->client : '';
if ($errors->any())
{
    $client = request()->old('client');
}
@endphp

<option {{ $client == 'o1' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="o1">o1</option>
<option {{ $client == 'o2' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="o2">o2</option>
<option {{ $client == 'o3' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="o3">o3</option>
```

Comment: Good thinking! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You no need to write long conditions, you can do like below.

```
<option {{ old('client', $project->client) == 'o1' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="o1">o1</option>
<option {{ old('client', $project->client) == 'o2' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="o2">o2</option>
<option {{ old('client', $project->client) == 'o3' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="o3">o3</option>
```

Comment: So when I try to use the page to create a project, $project is not defined..

Answer (score 0):

You could use an @if to see if the option is already set when the page re-loads or fails your validation..

```
<option value="">Select an answer...</option>
<option value="o1"
 @if($project->client == 'o1' || old('client') == 'o1')
 selected="selected"
 @endif()
>o1</option>
```

This has always worked for me. I think it might have something to do with your `isset()` since it's not testing to see if the variable is set, but rather what the value actually is.

Comment: So the problem in this case is if you change your select to an option that is above the one selected before. When the page re-loads, both old('client') and $project->client contain values. So the selected option will be the one that is lower on the list. And we don't want that.. Although the question was answered, thank you for taking some time to think and help. Appreciate it.